# vagrant ssh can't find the ssh executable

Tags: git, ssh, vagrant

I have the usual vagrant ssh problem with usual suggestion:

```
Try installing Cygwin, MinGW or Git, all of which
contain an SSH client
```

I have do this but I still have this problem. The only working solution that I've found is:

- install Git client
- open Git shell (sh.exe under `Program Files/Git/bin`)
- and then vagrant ssh on my project

As I said, this works but I have to switch from Windows Prompt (cmd.exe) to Git Shell (sh.exe). How can (can I?) run the `vagrant ssh` without switch the consoles in Windows?

Comment: I guess `vagrant` is not in your git shell's search path. When install git on windows, it asks to choose whether use windows's native cmd tool or git's, right? I am not sure.

Comment: I've installed it with Chocolatey, I don't know, i will check for this issue

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this is: I DON'T KNOW. :) But, there is a solution that worked for me:

1. Changed my IP address in my `Vagrantfile` to 192.168.33.11 (one value up)
2. Changed the connection tunnel IP in my Sequel Pro program for the database
3. Changed the IP address in my `/etc/hosts` file

I would still like to know why this was necessary, but this did serve as a solution to the problem - and probably a clue as to what happened.